# If Statement Checkbox Modal

Tags: html, w3.css

Code below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-col" id="login" style="width:300px">
  Subscribe to receive more interesting science experiments
  <p></p>
  Email  
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <p>I agree to the Terms and Conditions
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-grey">Sign Up</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span> 
        <p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
        <p>We will deliver the monthly experiment on the 1st of every Month</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i am trying to add an `IF` statement to the checkbox so that if its not ticked, the modal will come up with an error box instead of confirmation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you edit your post and show us what you've tried so far by yourself?

Comment: Should I just edit my code to add what I have tried so far?

Comment: Yes just edit your post

Comment: it is `onclick` and not `on click`

Comment: @jamsludge Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is that when the user clicks on the button `Sign Up` you need to check if the checkbox (I was marked as `#agree`) is `checked`. If so, display the modal. Read the code and let me know if something not clear.

```js
function subscribe() {
  var cb = document.getElementById('agree');
  if (cb.checked) {
      document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
  }
  else {
    alert('please agree to the terms');  
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" />

<div class="w3-col" id="login" style="width:300px">
  Subscribe to receive more interesting science experiments
  <p></p>
  Email  
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <p>I agree to the Terms and Conditions
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" />
    <button onclick="subscribe()" class="w3-grey">Sign Up</button>

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content">
      <div class="w3-container">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span> 
        <p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
        <p>We will deliver the monthly experiment on the 1st of every Month</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```